# create UIImage to be a border with color

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, uiimage, uicolor

I am using [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoIOS/FSCalendar) What I want to do is change the way of showing events. I want to put a coloured rectangle border around the cell with events. I did that by editing the cell background layer and worked fine, but now I realized that it is the wrong place to put my code as updating to the latest version of FSCalendar which will override my changes. 
One of what I can access by the calendar delegates is to set image to the cell, So I want to create image as rectange border with the event colour.
Here is an image of what I want:
[image: Calendar With events as rectangle border]

Any suggessions is appreicated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method will draw a bordered rectangle. I would make it class method and put into UIImage category for convenient use.

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color size:(CGSize)imageSize andBorderWidth:(CGFloat)borderWidth fillWithColor:(BOOL)fillWithColor{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);

    if(fillWithColor) {
        [color setFill];
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    } else {
        [color setStroke];
        CGContextStrokeRectWithWidth(context, rect, borderWidth);
    }

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

EDIT: Added `fillWithColor` parameter

Comment: Worked like charm. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can set border for UIImageView instead of set image as rectange border

```
cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
```

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. the thing I don't have access to the image view I just return a UIImage to in the delegate method.